# Media keys (FN7, FN8 & FN9) not working after update to 10.15.5

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, catalina

I updated my MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2018) to 10.15.5 (Build 19F101) last week just before I left the office for the weekend. This morning the keyboard media keys -- previous track | pause/play | next track -- no longer affect playback from Music, (the new iTunes,) but they ***were*** working in 10.15.4 as I use them multiple times every day. The volume mute/down/up keys work in Music as expected. I've checked the settings in System Preferences > Keyboard and they are correct, and I've never needed to change them.

Here's where it gets weirder: the pause/play media keys work whilst playing back Youtube video/audio in both Safari and Google Chrome, but the F11 & F12 keys do not lower or raise the volume. The mute key (F10) works, and muting occurs when I lower volume to zero with F11. The volume can be controlled by the volume slider in the video player GUI. This behaviour also happens when I view other non-Youtube videos, (from Vimeo, for example.)

I listen through harmon/kardon Nova bluetooth speakers and use a Matias bluetooth keyboard as well as an Apple Gen1 Magic trackpad, but the same problems occur when all bluetooth devices are disconnected and I use the MBA's built-in keyboard, trackpad and speakers.

Lastly, Keyboard Viewer does not effect the media keys either.

I'm mystified as later, the volume up/down now no longer works in the Music app so this is progressing in the wrong direction.

How can I trace what’s intercepting or disabling these so I can use the media keys again in all apps?

Comment: Was this fixed?